# How to unlock User accounts in AD using lockoutTime

Tags: c#, active-directory

I want to unlock user account in AD by setting the lockoutTime attribute to zero. The problem is that the value of the property is a System_ComObject. How do I set the value of the attribute to zero? I have used the following code to get the value of `lockOut`.

```cs
DirectoryEntry user = DirectoryEntry(DistinguishedName);

//user.Properties["lockoutTime"].Value is a System_Com object

long fileTicks = LongFromLargeInteger(user.Properties["lockoutTime"].Value);

private long LongFromLargeInteger(object largeInteger)
{
    System.Type type = largeInteger.GetType();
    type = largeInteger.GetType();
    int highPart = (int)type.InvokeMember("HighPart", 
    BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, largeInteger, null);
    int lowPart = (int)type.InvokeMember("LowPart", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, largeInteger, null);
    return (long)highPart << 32 | (uint)lowPart;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to do is this:

```
user.Properties["LockOutTime"].Value = 0;
user.CommitChanges();
```